# Running example Gem on Garfield++ (Linux)

Tags: compilation, root, physics

I am attempting to run the Gem example in Garfield++ but cannot run the cmake command in the Gem directory/build directory in Gem to generate the make files needed to run the example. This is the error I get (see image) [error_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhVGt.png)

How can I resolve it? I'm a newbie to this and would appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Garfield, so may be my answer is a bit naiive. Also, I noticed that the question is a couple of months old. But you know, heroes always come late :"D

In the cmake command you must provide the directory where the cmake list files are located. So, for example if you are inside this folder you should write the command cmake ./
If that also didn't work, try to check that the cmake list files are located inside your folder.